# Binding a drop down List with Model throwing an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I am trying to bind a drop down list to a model using entity framework and I am getting an error saying:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'OfficeName'.'
```

Below is my Model class:

```
 public partial class bookAssignment_new
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> Book { get; set; }
            public Nullable<int> OfficeID { get; set; }
            public string Office { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> OfficeName { get; set; }
      }
```

Below is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new bookAssignment_new();
            using (BookAssignmentEntities db = new BookAssignmentEntities())
            {
                var dbData = db.OfficeNames.ToList();
                model.OfficeName = GetSelectListItems(dbData);
            }
            return View();
        }
    
    
        private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetSelectListItems(IEnumerable<OfficeName> elements)
            {
                var selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
                foreach (var element in elements)
                {
                    selectList.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = element.OfficeID.ToString(),
                        Text = element.Office.ToString()
                    });
                }
                return selectList;
            }
```

I can see that right data is returned by GetSelectListItems().

My view has the following code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("OfficeName", Model.OfficeName)
       
    </div>
```

I am getting above error in the view. My OfficeName table is like so:

[image]

below is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `viewBag.OfficeName = GetSelectListItems(dbData);` not `model.OfficeName = GetSelectListItems(dbData);`!

Comment: I changed the code. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I probably don't have it right, but there is something wrong with how you are creating a local variable named `model`, and not using it after you set it up. The view won't have access to it.

Comment: I am very new in MVC. I just have six items inside the office table. I just want to display those six items as a drop down list